# Python Numpy recursive formula using Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recursion

I am getting an error message for the following code : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. 
This occurs for the line : emaInertia[i] = lambda_ * size + (1 - lambda_) * emaInertia[i-1]

I thought it was either using ' () ', or '[]'. However, both doesn't seem to work. Basically, I would like to use numpy array, and calculate a value Y(t) based on the previous value Y(t-1).

I can do this in pandaframes, but I would like to do it in Numpy as the array and matrix calculations in numpy are useful.

Kind regards

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def Momentum(bid, ask, bidQ, askQ, lambdaSlow = 0.01, lambda_ = 0.125, lambdaFast = 0.25, lambdaLead = 0.5, predSlow = 0, predFast = 0, points = 0, pred =0):
    bidQ = np.array(bidQ)
    askQ = np.array(askQ)
    bid = np.array(bid)
    ask = np.array(ask)
    size = askQ + bidQ
    prx = (bid * askQ + ask * bidQ) / size
    emaInertia = prx
    for i in range(0, len(emaInertia),1):
        emaInertia[i] = lambda_ * size + (1 - lambda_) * emaInertia[i-1]
    return emaInertia
```

Comment: When you ask about an error message you need to specify **where** it occurs, not must the message.  And in this case if you want us to test your function, you need to provide sample inputs.  We have  no idea what `bidQ` is - number, string, list, array? etc.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj, the line is : emaInertia[i] = lambda_ * size + (1 - lambda_) * emaInertia[i-1]

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example? That loop works fine when I use dummy variables. So it has something to do with your inputs. A short form of `emaInertia` and `size` for example.

Comment: I use the jupyter enviroment with the array input of >>> ask = [2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]; bid = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]; and bidQ =[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100], askQ = [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]... the inputs doesn't seem to matter... looks like a syntax error in my python code